# Do join constraints in a SQL right join do anything?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just had to fix a query that was doing a RIGHT JOIN with an additional constraint on the right hand side: `RIGHT JOIN b ON b.key = a.key AND b.active = 'Y'`

It appeared to be completely ignoring the `b.active` constraint. Is that a limitation of RIGHT JOIN? I swapped the tables over and moved the `b.active` constraint into the WHERE, I've never liked RIGHT JOIN and I think this has reinforced my aversion to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM a RIGHT JOIN
     b
     ON b.key = a.key AND b.active = 'Y'
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM b LEFT JOIN
     a
     ON b.key = a.key AND b.active = 'Y'
```

In both these cases the "driving" table for the outer join has a condition on it.  The logic of a left/right outer join is to keep all the records in one table, even when the `ON` condition does not evaluate to true.  Hence, a condition on that table would not result in any filtering.

If you want to filter on that table, then use a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM a RIGHT JOIN
     b
     ON b.key = a.key 
WHERE b.active = 'Y'
```

I should also note that the following two queries are *not* equivalent:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM a RIGHT JOIN
     b
     ON b.key = a.key AND b.active = 'Y';
```

and

```
SELECT . . .
FROM a RIGHT JOIN
     b
     ON b.key = a.key;
```

They return the same set of rows, assuming no duplicate keys in `b`.  However, the second will return matching rows in `a` when `b.active` is not `'Y'`.  The first will return `NULL` values for the columns in `a` in this case.  This is a subtle difference.  And, to be honest, I don't think I've ever found much use for it.

Comment: The "left outer join" and "right outer join" construct in SQL has always been a sore spot of sorts with me.  There really are only two kinds of outer joins: "full outer join" and "partial outer join".  Having the left/right distinction introduces a false concept.  It would be like noting that since division is not commutative (like partial outer join) we should have "/" - right division, and "\" - left division; with the only distinction being that the numerator and denominator are in reverse order of each other.  That would be absurd for division - it IS absurd for relational outer join.

Comment: @KenClement . . . SQL statements are not relational algebra.  The `FROM` clause is semantically processed in the order that the tables are written (or as dictated by parentheses).  Because of the nature of this processing, SQL  as a language needs to distinguish which is the "driving" table for a "partial" outer join.  `left` and `right` make a lot of sense to me for this purpose (although frankly, I'd be happy enough to eliminate `right join)..

Comment: @Gordon...You are relying on an faulty understanding probably based on a familiar implementation.  In fact not all SQL implementations have a "driving table" concept in how they implement query plans internally at least not one tied to the order tables are listed.  This notion is not inherent to SQL.  There is no, I repeat NO, good reason to have the "right" and "left" outer joins except as syntax sugar. Joins associate left to right regardless of the type of join.  Left and right partial outer joins differ only in the order of the operands (tables).  The "not a rel algebra" is a red herring.

Comment: @KenClement . . . My statement said nothing about query plans.  The "driving" table is a semantic concept about which table (if any) is keeping all its rows.  If you had a "partial join" keyword, you would still need to specify which of the operands is the one keeping all the rows.  If you want to argue that all joins should be `left join`s, I can't strongly argue -- in practice, I see no use for `right join`s.  However, you might consider that a considerable chunk of the world reads right-to-left rather than left-to-right, so perhaps they would find right joins more obvious.

Comment: My point is that the only difference between left join and right join is syntatic, not semantic.  A full outer join is semantically distinct.  I think there is NO pragmatic nor theoretical argument that justifies the current left join - right join definitions.  Even considering which way different parts of the world read text is still no consideration as that does not argue for which order the preserved table and non-preserved table should occur.  No language grammar provides for a "left divide" AND a "right divide" precisely for that reason.  In that case the numerator is always on the left.

Comment: To clarify, I am precisely arguing that there should only be a left outer join and that it only need be called "partial outer join".  It requires no great act of intellect to remember that the preserved table is on the left of the operand any more than it requires any particular mental acuity to remember that the numerator and the minuend are on the left while the denominator and the subtrahend are on the right of the division and subtraction operators respectively.

Comment: The reason I brought up the "driving table concept" and criticized it the way I did is that the term was used for Oracle databases to describe which table would be the "driving" table in a generated query plan.  It still gets used that way by "old school" SQL developers sometimes even though - starting with Sybase SQL Server (later the Microsoft product) query optimizers did not use the order tables are listed.  In those days the order one listed tables affected performance greatly.

Comment: Minor correction - I used the words minuend and subtrahend in their inverted sense above.  I do know the order of operands around the minus sign, but seem to have trouble remembering their names :-)

Comment: @KenClement . . . Surprisingly, I don't disagree with you.  `LEFT JOIN` is also preferable because of the way that `FROM` clauses are parsed.  However, standard SQL is a massive compromise, and users have to deal with lots of strangeness.  Don't lose sleep over this.